# Does a quasiperfect number exist? (n = sum of its divisors $\ne$ n,1)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Just like proper subsets of a set *A* are considered all subsets of *A* excluded *A* itself and $\emptyset$, some authors define *proper divisors* of an integer *n* all divisors but 1 and *n* itself: [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperDivisor.html), for instance.

I called *more than perfect* those integer positive numbers which are equal to the sum of their *strictly* proper divisors
$$n = \sum_
  {
  d | n}
  d; \quad {d\neq 1;\;d\neq n} 
$$

But I didn't find any. Can someone prove (or disprove) that they do not exist?

Comment: These are called quasiperfect numbers in the literature, and their nonexistence is still open.  Of course it is easy to see that $n$ must be square.

Comment: I edited the title to be much more specific, and to use standard terminology.

Comment: @ErickWong : why is it obvious that $n$ must be square?

Comment: @StefanSmith Because the sum of all divisors (including $1$ and $n$) is $2n+1$, which is odd.

Comment: @ErickWong : Thanks, Erick, but I still don't get it.  Let's take $n = 8$.  The sum of all the divisors of $8$ is $1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15$, which is odd, and $8$ is not a square.

Comment: @StefanSmith You are correct, I should have said it's easy to see that $n$ is either square or twice a square.

Comment: @StefanSmith The tricky part is if $n=2k^2$, then $\sigma(n) = 4k^2+1$, which is the sum of two coprime squares, so every divisor of $\sigma(n)$ must be $1$ mod $4$.  Since $\sigma(2^r)$ is $3$ mod $4$ for any $r \ge 1$, this rules out the possibility that $n$ is twice a square.

Comment: @ErickWong : can you give a reference for what you seem to be using, the fact (?) that if $\sigma(n)$ is odd, then $n$ is a square or twice a square?  If it is something that is in every number theory book, I have a few number theory books.

Comment: @StefanSmith I'm afraid I don't know a reference, but every number theory book will tell you that $\sigma(n)$ is multiplicative, so if it is odd then so is $\sigma(p^r)$ for every prime power factor of $n$.  When $p$ is odd this happens exactly when $r$ is even, so every prime (except $2$ as you point out) must occur an even number of times in $n$.

Comment: Sorry, but you could as well have asked about Fermat's theorem in 1990...